# How many variations of this grey background are there?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting, markdown

In Math Stack Exchange, it is common to find in an answer the question rewritten like this:

> Find the remainder when $2^{55}+1$ is divided by $33$

Then you find someone has hidden one of their answers like this:

> **Hint**: $2^{55}+1=(33-1)^{11}+1$

So my question is, are there any more variations of that grey background?

Comment: This does not have much to do with MathJax; it's Markdown that is used for formatting posts (except for mathematical formulas where MathJax is used). I changed the tag.

Comment: @quid Appreciate it. Thanks for the info

Comment: Also asked at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345432/177408

Answer (score 7):

The former is a block quote the later is a spoiler. There is also preformatted text, which might qualify. It looks like this.

```
This is preformatted text. It is especially useful for code.
You can get it by indenting the text with four spaces.
```

A feature or issue with this is that it will not break you lines, but instead will add a slider. Like this.

```
This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. This line is very long. Really it is.
```

Another difference is that it uses a mono spaced font. I think the main use case is for including pieces of code. Something similar can be obtained using backticks `like this`. For this one has to put (`), without the parenthesis, at the beginning *and* at the end. Note it must not be confused with ('), which has no particular function.